# Reverse look up of the VSCode command by typing the keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say I know a keyboard shortcut and I'd like to find in vscode the name of the command that it's tied to. Any way to do that (in vscode or via extension) by *actually typing the command*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts
```

[image: ctrl+s ctrl+k alt+k]